# What is the correct way to write this conditional statement?

Tags: php, conditional-content

I'd like to remove auto formatting 'wpautop' from specific pages. Here is what I've got, but it doesn't appear to work:

```
if ( is_page ( 'services' ) ) {
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
};
```

I am quite new to php, I have done some research to see how to write this statement, but I have had trouble finding an example that addresses my need. What would be the correct way to write this conditional statement?

Comment: Where are you adding this conditional? Are you using any hooks?

Comment: opps sorry. I am including this in functions.php, I am not using any hooks, but should I be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your function in the `template_redirect` hook. You need to first wait for wordpress to finish loading pages before you can add your hook to remove `wpautop`, otherwise your hook will simply get run over. So your funtion will look like this

```
function pietergoosen_remove_wpautop() {
if ( is_page ( 'services' ) ) {
remove_filter( 'the_content', 'wpautop' );
remove_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'wpautop' );
}
}

add_action( 'template_redirect', 'pietergoosen_remove_wpautop' );
```

Comment: I'm doing some research about template redirect. How did you come upon this solution?

Comment: This was actually a suggestion from one of the moderator on a similiar question I answered a while ago. The logic here is, and you can go and try it out yourself. Your `remove_filter` works perfectly when added in the `after_setup_theme` hook without the conditional statement. The problem is your conditional statement. Pages are loaded after the `after_setup_theme` hook, which renders your conditional ineffective. By the time `template_redirect` is executed, your pages are loaded, so any conditionals regarding pages can now be executed successfully

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I've found based off this [question at Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7697465/wordpress-remove-auto-generated-paragraphs-for-speciffic-custom-post-type)

You'll have to remove wpautop entirely then add it back in whenever needed, which I agree in the linked comment, is unfortunate:

```
remove_filter('the_content', 'wpautop');
remove_filter('the_excerpt', 'wpautop');

/** Change How The Content Works **/
function no_content_autop($content){
    global $post;

    if($post->post_type != 'services')
        return wpautop($content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content','no_content_autop');

/** Change How The Excerpt Works **/
function no_excerpt_autop($content){
    global $post;

    if($post->post_name != 'services')
        return wpautop($content);

    return $content;
}
add_filter('the_excerpt','no_excerpt_autop');
```

The question is old so you may want to watch this question for a day or two and see if somebody comes up with an improved answer.